# Limiting iframe designmode width after typing till a particular length

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, designmode

I have an **`iframe`** which is something like this :

```
<iframe id="topic-content" name="topic-content" class="form-fields" ></iframe>
```

I'm able to get it in design mode and everything is working just fine. But the problem arises when i can't limit the length of text that should be in one line.

If i start typing in it, it continues taking everything in one single line. I've set the width and height of it, tried fixing the **overflows -x** and **-y**,  but still not able to fix it.

Suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Load an existing file to the `iframe`, and use a contenteditable `div` instead of setting `document.desingMode = 'on'` in about:blank document. This way controlling styles within `iframe` is easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `contenteditable` property of a div, it'll be much easier to style.

Reference link : [contenteditable property](http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/contenteditable.cfm)